# How is euro sign stored in CLOB field in Oracle (AL32UTF8 character set)?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, clob, euro

I am using a web application which runs on WebSphere and interacts with an Oracle database (using the AL32UTF8 character set).

If I use the web application to input some text and then press the "save" button, I expect the text to be saved to a CLOB field in the Oracle database. There is functionality in the web application to view the text by retrieving it from the database.

When I input text containing the euro sign (€), press the "save" button, and view the text using using the web application, I found the euro sign was corrupted into "?".

I am trying to find whether the text is corrupted in the database.

1. Is the euro sign stored as "0xE2 0x82 0xAC" (3 bytes) in Oracle?
2. If this is the case, is there a database query which can confirm this? (Lets say that the table is called SOME_TABLE and the CLOB field is called SOME_FIELD.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's stored the same way as a `varchar2`, and does appear to be 3 bytes. You can use the [`dump` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions055.htm#sthref1091) to see how it's stored, though with a `clob` you'll need to extract the relevant characters (3-bytes worth in this case), e.g. with `dbms_lob.substr`. This is from 11gR2 on Linux:

```
create table t42 (x clob, y varchar2(10));

insert into t42(x, y) values ('€','€');

select dump(dbms_lob.substr(x,3,1)) from t42;

DUMP(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(X,3,1))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=6: 195,162,194,130,194,172

select dump(y) from t42;

DUMP(Y)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=6: 195,162,194,130,194,172
```

Or in hex:

```
select dump(dbms_lob.substr(x,3,1),16) from t42;

DUMP(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(X,3,1),16)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=6: c3,a2,c2,82,c2,ac
```